# Finding vector of same direction with smallest integer coordinates

Tags: number-theory, vector-calculus

To determine Miller Indices of crystal lattice planes I would need a stable algorithm which determines the smallest set of integer coordinates of a vector which has same direction as a given vector (e.g. through the unit vector). Let's try out an example:
When I have a simple integer vector given as $v=\{1.,2.,3.\}$ and I calculate the unit vector through

```
v={1.,2.,3.}
e=Normalize[v]
```

I get

```
{0.267261, 0.534522, 0.801784}
```

for e.
Using this vector now to reconstruct the original vector by trying to find the smallest integer coordinates e.g. through

```
Function[x,If[And@@(IntegerQ[#]&)/@x,x,(#/GCD@@#&)@Rationalize[x, 1/10^10]]]]
  @Normalize[{1.,2.,3.}]
```

is just working for vector coordinates which are greater than one (e.g. $\{1.5,2.,3\}$ is yielding the correct result $\{3,4,6\}$) but not for normalized vector coordinates. The above example yields a vector with very high integer coordinates.

I'm sure there is a simple solution to this but it seems that I'm a blockhead on this...

Comment: Is there a reason to use floating point numbers for the initial coordinates? Using exact numbers/integers would eliminate potential errors due to `Rationalize`.

Comment: @Ives Klett: There is a reason. As mentioned in the question, the issue is related to miller Indices. The input variable is an axis or plane norm vector with float coordinate components. The example with normalized coordinates was just used  for illustration.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Hope the suggested solutions are useful.

Comment: @Ives Klett. It is useful, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are probably much better ways, but this seems to work:

```
v={1.,2.,3.}
e=Normalize[v]

#/GCD @@ # &@Rationalize[e/Max[Abs[e]]]
```

> ```
> (*{1, 2, 3}*)
> ```

An alternative version (courtesy of J.M.) cleverly uses the second argument of `Normalize` and reads:

```
Normalize[Rationalize[Normalize[e, Composition[Max, Abs]]], GCD @@ # &]
```

Comment: Alternatively: `Normalize[Rationalize[Normalize[e, Composition[Max, Abs]]], GCD @@ # &]`

Comment: @J.M. much better, and educating as well. Would suggest you add as answer. Reversing the order of `Max` and `Abs` gets rid of the whole unpleasant `If` thing :D

Comment: Hmm, I think I'd prefer that you just edit your answer instead, if it's okay. I merely simplified your procedure, you see. :)

Comment: @J.M. o.k., done :)

Answer (score 3):

As noted by @YvesKlett, this can sometimes be done using `Rationalize`, with the idea being to get a common denominator.

For hard cases this would be a job for projective simultaneous rationalization. There is a former standard add-on package, available at [this library link](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/6776/), for such purpose.

Alternatively one can code a variant from scratch. I'll illustrate with the example from the original post.

We start with that initial vector.

```
v = {1., 2., 3.};
e = Normalize[v]

(* Out[71]= {0.267261241912, 0.534522483825, 0.801783725737} *)
```

We create a vector that will make its way into a lattice we later reduce.

```
big = 10^2;
rats = Prepend[Round[big*e/Min[e]], 1]

(* Out[73]= {1, 100, 200, 300} *)
```

It is fairly clear from the above that our quarry is `{1,2,3}`. But this is not always so obvious. We proceed as though it were not.

```
lat = Join[{rats}, Rest[big*IdentityMatrix[Length[rats]]]];
redlat = LatticeReduce[lat];
rows = Select[redlat, #[[1]] =!= 0 &];
rnum = Ordering[Map[N[#].# &, rows], 1][[1]];
xvals = Abs[(rows[[rnum, 1]]*Rest[rats] - Rest[rows[[rnum]]])/big]

(* Out[78]= {1, 2, 3} *)
```

There is some explanation of how/why this works in [these pdf slides](http://materials.dagstuhl.de/files/15/15251/15251.DanielLichtblau.Slides.pdf)

Comment: Can you present some mean cases? It might be interesting to compare the merits of the different approaches.

Comment: @Yves, Am I not a mean enough case?

Comment: (1) @YvesKlett, Okay, here goes. It requires "large" integers to mess up the `Rationalize` approach. That happens because `Rationalize` itself might fail to deliver a sufficiently good rationalization. So something like this gets into trouble: `SeedRandom[11122221];
v = RandomInteger[10^7, 3]
e = Normalize[N@v];
#/GCD @@ # &@Rationalize[e/Max[Abs[e]]]1

Comment: (2) @YvesKlett I should add that my method has its own sensitivity and in particular the multiplier `big` needs to be somewhat larger than the integers we hope to recover. For the example I showed in the last comment 10^10 suffices. With smaller multipliers we recover smaller integer sets that give "good" approximations in the sense of having close common ratios. Useful for working with approximations that might have some noise in them.

Comment: you sure are a wicked integer exorcist 

Comment: Exercist, actually. I once made a 20 give me 20. Try doing that many pushups on just two digits.

Comment: Base 3, eh?  Lemme try...  ouch,  no can do. BTW,  "equally uninformative",  that was a good one!

Comment: @YvesKlett "Unilluminating" just didn't look very good, at least with the fonts on my machine. Didn't want to write "uninspired" although I felt like it.

Comment: ...  almost, but not quite, entirely unlike uninspired...